# Implicit formula for surface of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, solid-of-revolution

I want to find the unit normal for a surface of revolution of the form

$F(t,s)=(r(t)cos(s),r(t)sin(s),z(t))$

where $\gamma(t)=(r(t),z(t))$ is a curve with unit speed and $r(t)>0$.

I know that if I have a submanifold $M$ given by some smooth $f$, s.t. $f^{-1}(0)=M$, then the unit normal is $\dfrac{grad \ f}{\Vert grad \ f \Vert}$ so I want to find such an $f$ for the above situation but I can't fix it. 
Is there a way to do it or do I need to try a different approach?

Referring to, for example, this [How to find the normal on a surface of revolution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660145/how-to-find-the-normal-on-a-surface-of-revolution) I can calculate the unit normal to be $(-z'(t)cos(s),-z'(t) sin(s), r'(t)$.(Is that correct? )
But I'm looking for a way to solve this using my above approach.

Comment: Try and normalize: $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial s} \wedge \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}?$$

Comment: Sometimes we get ideas stuck in our heads so hard that we fail to see how pointless they are. You know how to solve this. The other thread and Mindlack have both told you. Yes, there are functions $f$ - at least locally - for which $f^{-1}(0)$ is the surface of revolution. But in general, producing one is not easy. If $\gamma$ is well-behaved, solvable for $r$ in terms of $z$, then the function $f(r,\theta,z) = r(z) - z$ (expressed in cylindrical coordinates) will work. But overall, it will be more work than the solution you already know.

Comment: Ok, then I'm gonna stay with the solution I have, thanks!